# Impute Missing Values Using K-Nearest Neighbors

Tags: python-3.x

i'm trying to impute missing values with KNN in python so i have downloaded a package named fancyimpute that contain the methode KNN then when i want to import it i get this Error ImportError: cannot import name 'KNN'
please help me

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

I had seen this same exact error message, and it was because python was confused about some other file names in the same folder that is was loading instead of library files. Try cleaning the folder, renaming your files, etc.